# How to solve word generation error in Hangman Game?

Tags: python

> Q.Building Hangman Game. In the game of Hangman, the player only has 6 incorrect guesses (head, body, 2 legs, and 2 arms) before they lose the game. We loaded a random word list and picked a word from it. Then we wrote the logic for guessing the letter and displaying that information to the user. In this exercise, we have to put it all together and add logic for handling guesses.

So, I made the program with some help but stil there is a silly little problem coming that is the generation of a random word.

Please tell what I am doing wrong and if you would run this program that would help you better understand what I am saying.

```
import random


def generate():
    Words = []
    with open('sowpods.txt', 'r') as f:
        line = f.readline().strip()
        Words.append(line)
        while line:
            line = f.readline().strip()
            Words.append(line)
    index = random.randint(0, len(Words) - 1)
    return Words[index]


def ask_user_for_next_letters():
    letter = input("Guess Your Letter: ")
    return letter.strip().upper()


def generate_word_string(word, letter_guessed):
    output = []
    for letter in word:
        if letter in letter_guessed:
            output.append(letter.upper())
        else:
            output.append("_")
    return " ".join(output)


print("Welcome To Hangman!")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Secret = generate()
    letter_to_guess = set(Secret)
    correct_letters = set()
    incorrect_letters = set()
    num_guesses = 0
    while (len(letter_to_guess) > 0) and num_guesses < 6:
         guess = ask_user_for_next_letters()
         #Checks If We Already Guessed That Letter
         if guess in correct_letters or guess in incorrect_letters:
             print("You Already Guessed That!")
             continue
         #If The Guess Was Correct
         if guess in letter_to_guess:
         #Update The letter_to_guess
             letter_to_guess.remove(guess)
         #Update The Correct Letters Guessed
             correct_letters.add(guess)
         else:
             incorrect_letters.add(guess)
             #Only Update The Number Of Guesses
             #If You Guess Incorrectly
             num_guesses += 1

         word_string = generate_word_string(Secret, correct_letters)
         print(word_string)
         print("You Have {} Guesses Left".format(6 - num_guesses))
     #Tell The User They Have Won Or Lost
     if num_guesses < 6:
         print("Congratulations! You Correctly Guessed The Word {}!".format(Secret))
     else:
         print("Loser!".format(Secret))
```

Comment: Please note specifically what you expect to happen, what exactly is happening that you need help with. There isn't an answerable question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Modifications**

1. Corrects routine *generate* to provide random words.
2. Always convert users input to uppercase
3. Convert selected word to upper case
4. slight change in variable naming so it conforms to PEP 8 (i.e. 'secret' rather than 'Secret')

**Code**

```
import random

def generate():
    words = []
    with open('sowpods.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
          line = line.strip()
          if line:
            words.append(line)

    return random.choice(words).upper()

def ask_user_for_next_letters():
    letter = input("Guess Your Letter: ")
    return letter.strip().upper()

def generate_word_string(word, letter_guessed):
    output = []
    for letter in word:
        if letter in letter_guessed:
            output.append(letter.upper())
        else:
            output.append("_")
    return " ".join(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Welcome To Hangman!")

    secret = generate()

    letter_to_guess = set(secret)

    correct_letters = set()
    incorrect_letters = set()

    num_guesses = 0
    while (len(letter_to_guess) > 0) and num_guesses < 6:
         guess = ask_user_for_next_letters()
         #Checks If We Already Guessed That Letter
         if guess in correct_letters or guess in incorrect_letters:
             print("You Already Guessed That!")
             continue
         #If The Guess Was Correct
         if guess in letter_to_guess:
         #Update The letter_to_guess
             letter_to_guess.remove(guess)
         #Update The Correct Letters Guessed
             correct_letters.add(guess)
         else:
             incorrect_letters.add(guess)
             #Only Update The Number Of Guesses
             #If You Guess Incorrectly
             num_guesses += 1

         word_string = generate_word_string(secret, correct_letters)
         print(word_string)
         print("You Have {} Guesses Left".format(6 - num_guesses))
     #Tell The User They Have Won Or Lost
    if num_guesses < 6:
        print("Congratulations! You Correctly Guessed The Word {}!".format(secret))
    else:
        print("Loser!".format(secret))
```

Comment: The Solution Was Right.